# Setting Cache with the PlayFramework

Tags: java, caching, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I'm using the playFramework 2.3.5 with Java, want to set sth. in the Cache and want to display it in the next step. So my Code in the Application.java looks like:

```
public static Result addText() {

    Input input = new Input("Test");

    Cache.set("1", input);

    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
}

public static Result getText(){

    Input output = (Input) Cache.get("1");
    try{
    String out = output.getText();
    return ok(Html.apply(out));

    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        return ok(index.render("Fail"));
    }

}
```

And my code in routes looks like:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /                           controllers.Application.addText()
GET     /output                     controllers.Application.getText()
```

The Input class looks sth. like this:

```
public class Input {

  public String text;

  public Input(String text){
    this.text = text;
  }

  public String getText(){
    return text;
  }

}
```

When I want to test it, localhost:9000/output throws a NullPointerException. Can someone say, why the Object isn't in the cache?

Comment: At what line is exception thrown? Btw, is `Input` serializable?

Comment: The NullPointerException is thrown at: String out = output.getText();
I added the Input class in my question.

Comment: Do you actually invoke POST action on `/` url? If you use browser and navigate to `/` url, play will invoke `controllers.Application.index()` action.

Comment: Ok I made a mistake while testing it. The cache can be set by a GET request.
GET    /outputs                           controllers.Application.addText()
saved it and /output shows the String. But maybe there is a better way to solve the problem

Comment: What exactly is the problem now? Did fixing your mistake solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dev mode (play run), the Play Cache does not fully work.  But a larger issue is that a cache, by definition, can be flushed at any time.  Your app needs to be able to handle Cache.get returning null for something that you recently put in the cache.